# How does current flow in a conductor if the electric field in a conductor is always 0?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, maxwell-equations

How do EM waves propagate inside waveguides made of conductors and how does current flow inside a conductor from a high voltage to a low voltage if the Electric field inside a perfect conductor is = 0 ? What is the driving force that causes the charges to move ?

Comment: The electric field is zero if the charges do not move = electrostatics. When there is an electric field mobile charge carrier move.

Comment: @Andrea Escalante - Could you, please, clarify whether  you generally see the problem in conductors or whether your question is restricted to "perfect" conductors, like superconductors?

Answer (score 0):

The electric field in a conductor is only zero in a *static situation* where the charges on the surface of the conductor can rearrange so that the electric field in the interior and tangentially at the surface become zero. This is a consequence of the high concentration of electrons and thus conductance of the metal. If you apply a voltage between two points of a conductor, there will be an electric field in the metal that produces a current. That's how all electric wires work.

Inside a hollow conductor (wave guide) EM waves can propagate while the boundary conditions to the metal produce surface currents in the metal.

Comment: The thing that keeps a simple circuit from being static is that the battery or other power supply keeps pushing on the circuit. The steady state will only be reached when the batter comes to chemical equilibrium.

Comment: *"The electric field in a conductor is only zero in a static situation"* - Doesn't the OP specifically mention the case that the conductor is a *perfect* conductor?  A perfect conductor, [by definition](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/perfect.pdf), has zero electric field inside.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - The OP only mentions a "conductor". For the electric field to be zero inside a conductor under "static conditions", you only need a conductor with sufficiently high conductivity $\sigma$ so that Maxwell's relaxation time $\tau=\frac {\epsilon}{\sigma}$ is short compared to the time scale of the experiment.

Comment: I quote the OP:  *"how does current flow inside a conductor from a high voltage to a low voltage if the Electric field inside a **perfect** conductor is = 0 "*

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - You are right, there he put the adjective "perfect" in. However, it doesn't appear in the title of the question: *How does current flow in a conductor if the electric field in a conductor is always 0?* Obviously, he assumes that the electric field is always zero inside a conductor (not only in an electrostatic situation)  and thus sees a contradiction to the case where a current flows when an external EMF is applied to a conductor. I think that a superconductor was not on his mind in this question.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I got curious about the link. I do not see anything inside it which contradicts the fact that current flows between two points kept at different potential in a conductor and whatever a superconductor is. All the discussion is relevant to the magnetic properties. If I had understood correctly.

Comment: *"Obviously, he assumes that the electric field is always zero inside a conductor (not only in an electrostatic situation)"* - freecharly, the mere *fact* that the OP mentions *perfect* conductor does not justify your conclusion at all (in my judgment).  It seems to me that, given the mention of a *perfect* conductor, one might consider addressing the perfect conductor case in one's answer rather than glossing over it entirely.  Perhaps I will do that should I find the inclination.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri -  It would only be an enrichment for everybody if  you could spare the time to expound on the special case of a "perfect conductor".

Comment: freecharly, not bad.  Have you been practicing?